# plotting an average line in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Plotting an average line in ggplot.

I have the following data;

```
structure(list(Region.in.country = c("Andalucia", "Aragon", "Asturias", 
"Canary Islands", "Cantabria", "Castilla-La Mancha", "Castilla y Leon", 
"Cataluna", "Comunidad Valenciana", "Extremadura", "Galicia", 
"Islas Baleares", "La Rioja", "Madrid", "Murcia", "Navarra", 
"Pais Vasco"), count = c(540L, 117L, 74L, 362L, 36L, 150L, 299L, 
952L, 797L, 72L, 283L, 353L, 39L, 1370L, 302L, 46L, 255L)), .Names = c("Region.in.country", 
"count"), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), na.action = structure(18L, .Names = "18", class = "omit"))
```

I am trying to add an average line across the bar plot in ggplot 2. The average line is the avergae of the `count` column over the 17 regions.

`sum(region$count) / 17`

```
 ggplot(data = region, aes(x = Region.in.country, y = count)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity") +
   geom_line(data = region, aes(355.7059)) +
   coord_flip()
```

The above code returns an error

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: I am not getting any error with your data

Comment: try `geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 355.7059))`  instead of `geom_line(...)`. (alas, this task is not as quixotic as it appears (one can't help but notice La Mancha in the `Region.in.county` column).)

Comment: really... I have edited the original post and included my graphic

Comment: Great! thanks bouncyball - it worked perfect! One additional question, is it possible to put the equation in the geom_hline. E.G. `geom_hline(aes(yintercept =  sum(region$count) / nrow(region)))`

Comment: Since you specified `data` in your `ggplot` call, you can succintly type: `geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(count)))`

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks! I tried the same thing but with `geom_line` which gave me the errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job. Credit to `bouncyball` for suggesting `aes(yintercept = mean(count))` instead of `yintercept = 355.7059`

```
  ggplot(region, aes(x= reorder(Region.in.country, count), count))+
    geom_bar(stat ="identity")+
    coord_flip()+
    xlab("Region")+
    ylab("Counts")+
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(count)))
```

[image]

If you want to create an ordered bar plot (by the numeric value), always remember to use `reorder()` on the column beforehand. **It'll be unsorted otherwise even if you use** `arrange()` **or** `sort()` **to sort the data before plotting it.** If you don't use `reorder()` on it, it'll be sorted by the corresponding id variable, `Region.in.country` in alphabetical order (as shown in the other answer posted after this one).

Comment: Yes this works perfect also. Thank you. I like bouncyball solution of adding `geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(count)))` instead of the number 355.7059

Comment: Let me edit my post to accommodate for your adjustment (will give credit at top). Nice.

Comment: Another interesting answer would be to check the `stat_summary()` function. As in `ggplot2::stat_summary(fun.y = mean, ggplot2::aes(x = 1, yintercept = ..y..), geom = "hline")`. More details can be found [on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330348/plot-hline-at-mean-with-geom-bar-and-stat-identity)

Answer (score 0):

Use geom_hline as follows:

```
avg <- mean(region$count)

region %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Region.in.country, y = count)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = avg)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: result of the code]