# Plot hline at mean with geom_bar and stat="identity"

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, geom-bar

I have a barplot where the exact bar heights are in the dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:6], y=c(1:6, 1:6 + 1), g=rep(x = c("a", "b"), each=6))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=g, group=g)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]

Now I want to add **two** hlines displaying the mean of all bars per group. All I get with

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=g, group=g)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, aes(yintercept=..y.., group=g), geom="hline")
```

is

[image]

As I want to do this for a arbitrary number of groups as well, I would appreciate a solution with ggplot only.

I want to avoid a solution like this, because it does not rely purely on the dataset passed to ggplot, has redundant code and is not flexible in the number of groups:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=g, group=g)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(df$y[df$g=="a"]), col="red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(df$y[df$g=="b"]), col="green")
```

Thanks in advance!

Edits:

- added dataset
- comment on resulting code
- changed the data and plots to clarify the question

Comment: any reproducible dataset?

Comment: I am not sure what we are aiming for... you want a single command for that `ggplot()+geom_bar()`? or what?

Comment: sry, forgot to add the dataset. I would like to have a solution like ggplot() + geom_bar() + stat_summary(geom="hline")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your first approach is almost there:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = g, group = g)) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge") + # geom_col is equivalent to geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, aes(x = 1, yintercept = ..y.., group = g), geom = "hline")
```

[image: plot]

According to the help file for `stat_summary`:

> `stat_summary` operates on unique x; ...

In this case, `stat_summary` has inherited the top level aesthetic mappings of `x = x` and `group = g` by default, so it would calculate the mean y value ***at each x*** for each value of g, resulting in a lot of horizontal lines. Adding `x = 1` to `stat_summary`'s mapping overrides `x = x` (while retaining `group = g`), so we get a single mean y value for each value of g instead.

Comment: Hey! Just to chime in, when doing this with with a datetime variable on the x-axis, setting `x=1` or `x=NULL` or `x=lubridate::today()` all result in `Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only`. Any ideas?

Comment: replace `x=1` with `x=as.Posixct("2020-01-01")`

Comment: or better even: replace `x=1` with `mean(.data[[x]],na.rm=TRUE)`, so that the reference point falls within your data

Comment: Why are dots added to `..y..` in `stat_summary`?